# How to display data using FlatList and webView in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created flatList and I am passing array of objects. Each object has title and data array. In renderItem of FlatList I am trying to display text which is title and  but it gives error as `null`. How can I display data using flatList i.e I want to display title and data key from each array of objects.

Example data:
[image]

Code:

```
<FlatList
                    data={specificationsData}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    renderItem={({item}) =>
                    <View style={styles.flatview}>
                        <Text style={styles.name}>{item.title}</Text>                     
                        <WebView originWhitelist={['*']}
                        source={{ html: item.data }}/>  <--- gives error
                    </View>
                    }
                    />
```

I want to display html data from each object and title so it displays `item.title` as text properly but item.data doesn't work if I pass item.data in WebView how can I display the HTML content using webView and FlatList ?

Comment: Are you sure you need a webview? this seems like it might be unnecessarily complicated

Comment: @kai Yes without webView how can I display html content ? If I use `<Text> {item.data}</Text>` then it displays `<p><span> ......` on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a webView, I suggest you try https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html library to display HTML content.

Maybe something like this:

```
...
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';
...
<FlatList
    data={specificationsData}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    renderItem={({item}) =>
    <View style={styles.flatview}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>{item.title}</Text>                             
        <HTML html={item.data} />
    </View>
    }
/>
```

Comment: I have tried it on ios but it is breaking some content

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the app and the console.log of your item.data? It should work, I use it in my projects. Lets see what you're getting and I'll help you fix that.